Multilevel segmented regression
I have some data on the proportion of healthcare workers that are vaccinated against disease X each year in several healthcare institutions. I want to evaluate the impact of two large-scale interventions on the outcome of interest (proportion of vaccinated healthcare workers), which is bounded between 0 and 1.
I'm planning to run a segmented regression model. Given that I have repeated measures I was thinking using a multilevel binomial model.
My thoughts were to use the id of the institution as a random intercept (baseline proportions can vary in different institutions) and time as a random slope :
binom_model <- glmer(vax_proportion ~ time + intervention1 + time_since1 + intervention2 + time_since2 + (1 + time| institution_id), weights = denominator, family = "binomial")
Where
vax_proportion = proportion of vaccinated individuals,
time = an integer in 1-12 (I have data over 12 years),
intervention1 = 0/1 (coded as 0 before intervention1 and 1 after),
time_since1 = starts counting at 1... when intervention 1 started, it is 0 before,
intervention2 = 0/1 (coded as 0 before intervention2 and 1 after),
time_since2 = starts counting at 1... when intervention 2 started, it is 0 before,
denominator = the denominator used to calculate the proportion
Do you think that the above model would be sufficient to account for autocorrelation due to repeated measures ?
While the random effects in the model have time as a random slope, when i try to add more random effects like (1 + time_since1|id) + (1 + time_since2|id) the model crashes.
My understanding is that while my model accounts for freely varying time effect before intervention1 it does not do the same for the periods between intervention 1 or 2 and after 2.
